# Where did Samson Raphael Hirsch write "the catechism of the Jew is his calendar"?

Tags: calendar, quotations, samson-raphael-hirsch

There are lots of articles and books that say "Samson Raphael Hirsch famously wrote 'the catechism of the Jew is his calendar'" - but what is the mareh makom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source appears to be his [Collected Writings of Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/087306786X), in the chapter Tishrei I which starts

> **The catechism of the Jew consists of his calendar**. On the pinions of
> time which bear us through life, God has inscribed the eternal words
> of His soul-inspiring doctrine, making days and weeks, months and
> years the heralds to proclaim His truths.

See [here](https://web.stevens.edu/golem/llevine/rsrh/tishrei_I_41_51_colected_II.pdf) for the full text.

Comment: He didn't write in English I assume?

Comment: No in German, in his Gesammelte Schriften (Collected Writings)

Comment: Can you get the quote in German so we can judge this translation?

Comment: I started with the German (which I speak) "Der Katechismus des Juden ist sein Kalender", since this was the OP question, which led me to the source I quoted in German, which led me to the translation. I have a number of RSRH books but not this series though

Comment: @DoubleAA https://archive.org/details/gesammelteschrif00hirs/page/n17/mode/2up: "Des Juden Katechismus ist sein Kalender."

Comment: Fantastic! This community is amazing. Moadim LeSimcha!